# Test EntityManager with JUnit and Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, entitymanager

I have tried to test the following class, but I have been unsuccessful.

```
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public int sendToTableOne()
    {
        return em.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO TABLE_ONE"
                        + " SELECT * FROM TABLE_TWO")
                .executeUpdate();
    }
```

How can I test this class?

I'm using JUnit Jupiter on Spring framework.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? Did you try anything with [`@DataJpaTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html)?

Comment: @dan1st no, I didn't. I'm going to try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's a good solution, but I obtain 100% coverage.

```
@Mock
EntityManager entityManager;

@Mock
Query query;

@InjectMocks
ThSwapDaoImpl daoImpl;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() throws Exception {
}

@Test
void test() {
    
    when(entityManager.createNativeQuery(anyString())).thenReturn(query);
    when(query.executeUpdate()).thenReturn(1);
    assertEquals(daoImpl.sendToHistorical(), 1);

}
```

Comment: You need to use this annotation: @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)